# loop through the gridview and see if the checkbox is checked then get the first column value using ASP .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

i want to loop through the gridview and see if the checkbox is checked then get the first column value using ASP .net gridview 
 the code   looks correct ...but when i add the else statement to the code and then put into   the else an alert then when i cheacked in gridview and click on the button1 they show me the alert instead of execut the command 
i'd try this but it does not work :

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        For i As Integer = 0 To DossierGV.Rows.Count - 1
            If DirectCast(DossierGV.Rows(i).Cells(0).FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox).Checked = True Then
                execSQL("update OFPPT_Envoyer set vue = '1' where ID_Dossier = " & (DossierGV.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text), "e")
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

and ths is the gridview :

```
 &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Vue" />
           <asp:GridView ID="DossierGV" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
               AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID_Dossier" 
               DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
               <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Choisir">
                       <EditItemTemplate>
                           <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                       </EditItemTemplate>
                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                       </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="ID_Dossier" HeaderText="ID_Dossier" ReadOnly="True" 
                       SortExpression="ID_Dossier" />
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="I ....................
..............................
```

Comment: Your code looks correct, so what is the error or issue?

Comment: Are you 'finding' the control?  Is the execSQL ever running?

Comment: it looks correct ... when i add the else statement to the code and then put into the else an alert when i cheacked in gridview they show me the alert instead of execut the command

Comment: @SteveWellens yes .... it looks correct ... when i add the else statement to the code and then put into   the else an alert then when i cheacked in gridview they show me the alert instead of execut the command

Comment: @Yassineedouiri - What is the value of DossierGV.Rows(i).Cells(2).Text?  Is it space padded causing the WHERE clause to fail?  Is there a matching record?

Comment: @SteveWellens no it's a numérique value  and i mean DossierGV.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text not DossierGV.Rows(i).Cells(2).Text

Comment: @Yassineedouiri - Does the SQL Update string you are generating work in an SQL window...like in Management Studio...outside of your program?

Comment: yes yes dudde .... i repeat : when i add the else statement to the code and then put into the else an alert then when i cheacked in gridview and click on the button  they show me the alert instead of execut the command

Comment: @SteveWellens hi dudde can we just connect to the timeviewer and u can see what happen ?

Comment: @Yassineedouiri please put the code in error too in your question

Comment: @HatSoft there is no error when i add the else statement to the code and then put into the else an alert then when i cheacked in gridview and click on the button they show me the alert instead of execut the command

Comment: @Yassineedouiri where are you adding this else statement, thats what I want to see in your question because thats what is the issue you are your code have and you have not mentioned it

Comment: i find out the probleme ... the all problems is be couse i have add Me.DataBind() in the load so tnksssssss friends

Answer (score 0):

the problem because i have add the (( `Me.DataBind()` )) in the load event